# Position: Fixed Div Covers Images

Tags: html, css

So, Im trying to make an image stuck to the bottom of the page with position:fixed (kinda like navigation bar). The problem is that I have text somewhere in the center of the page and when I zoom, this image covers some of the text and it cant be seen.

CSS:

```
.bottom {
    display: block;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height: 70px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

p.BrunchENG_TXT{
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60%;
    color:#7b0d4c;
    font-family:"Verdana";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
 <p class="BrunchENG_TXT"> 
  <b>Brunch</b> 
  </br>
  The weekends are holydays, giving us the chance to share special moments with the people we love the most….We welcome everybody each Sunday starting 11 o’clock so that all of you can enjoy fully this precious time and recharge with healthy food and energy for the day….Welcome to the Sunday Bruch @ Mumbai Burgas - the menus are composed with special attention to the children and the vegetarians and are published well in advance on our FB page.
 </p> 

 <div>
  <img src="images/repetB.jpg" class="bottom">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please include your html?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There, all the code, just text and image, nothing special, I want the Fixed image not to cover the text.

Comment: should the image be still visible when scroll?

Comment: @KpTheConstructor it's position:fixed, it should be?

Comment: Position fixed elements take them out of the flow of the document. Your text and image have no idea in what space they each exist. Your best bet is to pad the bottom of the text with enough of a margin that it pushes the document far enough down to give the image space to display.

Comment: Thanks @Lewis It worked!

Answer (score 1):

I used `margin-bottom: 100px;` and it worked!

Comment: Does it work so well if you resizes your window? Also think about bigger/smaller screens and mobiles :)

Comment: It fits well with my code and I see no problem for now, so yes, It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code is working for me

CSS:

```
 .bottom {
 display: block;
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
 height: 70px;
 bottom: 0px;
 }

  p.BrunchENG_TXT{
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  color:#7b0d4c;
  font-family:"Verdana";
  }

  #img-footer{
    height: 100px; /* change 100px by height of the picture "repetB.jpg"*/
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
 <p class="BrunchENG_TXT"> <b>Brunch</b> </br>
 The weekends are holydays, giving us the chance to share special moments with the people we love the most….We welcome everybody each Sunday starting 11 o’clock so that all of you can enjoy fully this precious time and recharge with healthy food and energy for the day….Welcome to the Sunday Bruch @ Mumbai Burgas - the menus are composed with special attention to the children and the vegetarians and are published well in advance on our FB page.
 </p> 

<div id="img-footer">
<img src="images/repetB.jpg" class="bottom">
</div>
</div>
```